# Reversing a bitwise operation

Tags: bitwise-operators

If I have for example: `a = (b << 8) | (c << 4) | d` how would I get `b` `c` and `d` from `a`? Or if I had `a` and `d` and needed to get `b` and `c`?

Comment: Do you know something about the range of possible values for `b,c,d`?  Try doing some examples and writing them in binary.

Comment: Code like that could come up if you were packing 4-bit values in a larger int, in which case e.g. `d==a&15` and `c==(a>>4)&15` make sense (15 being 1111 binary). But Henry Twist's answer is right that _in general_ "reverse these bitwise operations" doesn't have a unique solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a single solution for a problem like this (unless in very specific cases). The OR operator (`|`) doesn't have an inverse, so even the simplified problem of:

`a = b | c`

where `a` and `c` are known, is not solvable (at least to get a single solution).

---

For a more practical example, you can consider something super simple:

`11 = 10 | c`

then `c` could either be `11` or `01` and the number of solutions keep growing with the number of bits.